# fetching data from map api

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

Iam using mapbox and trying to fetch some data from this api :
[JSON](https://www.followmee.com/api/tracks.aspx?key=0949835bf9d61dbe076ffc0d9330ce50&username=OleJacobsen&output=json&function=currentfordevice&deviceid=12563074)

```
 async function getLocation(updateSource) {
            // Make a GET request to the API and return the location of the ISS.
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544',
                    { method: 'GET' }
                );
                const { latitude, longitude } = await response.json();
                // Fly the map to the location.
                map.flyTo({
                    center: [longitude, latitude],
                    speed: 0.5
                });
                // Return the location of the ISS as GeoJSON.
                return {
                    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                    'features': [
                        {
                            'type': 'Feature',
                            'geometry': {
                                'type': 'Point',
                                'coordinates': [longitude, latitude]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                };
            } catch (err) {
                // If the updateSource interval is defined, clear the interval to stop updating the source.
                if (updateSource) clearInterval(updateSource);
                throw new Error(err);
            }
        }
    });
```

so when I tried to fetch the JSON link I get an error ! Is this because the JSON that I want to use has some issues ??
This is the codebase :
https://jsfiddle.net/dhap8430

Comment: the error could be caused by anything

Comment: actually the error is only related to the json link. the origin link https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544 works perfectly fine

Comment: it is unknown what error you are talking about, so the cause is also unknown